# How to remove more than one match in Java using replaceAll()?

Tags: java, regex

Hi there I am trying to remove two or more words in a String with the replaceAll method in Java
but I am not good in regex at all and I have not been able to do it.
So, here is the code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s= "@class::menu-select @id::calibration-content";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[(@class::)(@id::)]",""));
}
```

But when I run this what I get is the following text **menu-eet brton-ontent**
By the way the words I am trying to remove are *@class::* and *@id::*
Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String#replaceAll` accepts a regular expression, and you're passing it a character class of substrings you're looking to replace, which isn't correct.

Instead, you could change the regular expression to look specifically for the substrings:

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("@class::|@id::",""));
```

This results in the following output:

```
menu-select calibration-content
```

Keep in mind that there are more efficient methods of removing substrings from a `String` than regex.

Answer (score 1):

The expression you used contains `[]` which matches on the range of characters inbetween. Just use something like:

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("@(class|id)::",""));
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should work

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s= "@class::menu-select @id::calibration-content";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("@class::|@id::", ""));
}
```

It prints

```
menu-select calibration-content
```